# How do I use glTexParameterfv in LWJGL?

Tags: lwjgl

I've looked throught all GL** classes but am unable to find the method glTexParameterfv. The default glTexParamteri.... methods are in GL11. How can i change the border color of  a texture in lwjgl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is called [`glTexParameter`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glTexParameter(int,%20int,%20java.nio.FloatBuffer)) (without the suffix) in LWJGL 2 and can be found in `GL11` as well.

Since LWJGL 3 it is called [`glTexParameterfv`](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glTexParameterfv(int,%20int,%20java.nio.FloatBuffer)) again.